# SVG Text Not Aligning in Edge

Tags: svg

I cannot find a solution to my issue here, so I am posting a new question. The text in my SVG here is not aligned properly in Edge. It works fine in Firefox, but when I open the page in Edge, the text is crooked and spaced unevenly. It looks great in Firefox though. I have tried numerous fixes, but nothing seems to be working. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Javascript

```
const rad = Math.PI / 180;

let cx = 50, cy = 100, R = 50, r = 35, A = 40 , a = 5, o=4;
// o for offset
svgGroupC.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", `rotate(${-90 -(A / 2) - a} ${cx} ${cy})`);

// control points for the quadratic Bézier
let px1 = cx + R * Math.cos(0);
let py1 = cy + R * Math.sin(0);
let px2 = cx + R * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py2 = cy + R * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px3 = cx + r * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py3 = cy + r * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px4 = cx + r * Math.cos(0);
let py4 = cy + r * Math.sin(0);

// points used to draw the shape
let x11 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos(0);
let y11 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin(0);

let x1 = cx + R * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y1 = cy + R * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x2 = cx + R * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y2 = cy + R * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x21 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y21 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x31 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y31 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x3 = cx + r * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y3 = cy + r * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x4 = cx + r * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y4 = cy + r * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x41 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos(0);
let y41 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin(0);

// Rounded corners with quadratic Bézier curves
    d = `M${x1},${y1} 
         A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         Q${px2},${py2} ${x21},${y21} 
         L${x31},${y31}
         Q${px3},${py3} ${x3},${y3}
         A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         Q${px4},${py4} ${x41},${y41}
         L${x11},${y11}
         Q${px1},${py1} ${x1},${y1}Z`;

svgPath.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
```

HTML

```
<svg viewBox="0 40 100 40">
  <g id="svgGroupC" >
       <style type="text/css">

          @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
          text{
            font-size: 4pt;
              fill: #ffffff;
              text-anchor: middle;
              font-family: 'Raleway';
              z-index: 2;
          }

  </style>
      <path id="svgPath"/>
       <text>
         <textpath xlink:href="#svgPath" startOffset="53%" >
            <tspan dx="14" dy="9">CLIENTS</tspan>
      </textpath>
    </text>   
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that SVGs often have poor alignment with small dimensions. Multiplying all values by 10 makes the text in Edge line up properly:

**SVG**

```
<svg viewBox="0 400 1000 400">
  <g id="svgGroupC" >
       <style type="text/css">

          @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
          text{
            font-size: 40pt;
              fill: #ffffff;
              text-anchor: middle;
              font-family: 'Raleway';
              z-index: 2;
          }

  </style>
      <path id="svgPath"/>
       <text>
         <textpath xlink:href="#svgPath" startOffset="53%" >
            <tspan dx="140" dy="90">CLIENTS</tspan>
      </textpath>
    </text>   
  </g>
</svg>
```

**JS**

```
const rad = Math.PI / 180;

let cx = 500, cy = 1000, R = 500, r = 350, A = 40 , a = 5, o=4;
// o for offset
svgGroupC.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", `rotate(${-90 -(A / 2) - a} ${cx} ${cy})`);

// control points for the quadratic Bézier
let px1 = cx + R * Math.cos(0);
let py1 = cy + R * Math.sin(0);
let px2 = cx + R * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py2 = cy + R * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px3 = cx + r * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py3 = cy + r * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px4 = cx + r * Math.cos(0);
let py4 = cy + r * Math.sin(0);

// points used to draw the shape
let x11 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos(0);
let y11 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin(0);

let x1 = cx + R * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y1 = cy + R * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x2 = cx + R * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y2 = cy + R * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x21 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y21 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x31 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y31 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x3 = cx + r * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y3 = cy + r * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x4 = cx + r * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y4 = cy + r * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x41 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos(0);
let y41 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin(0);

// Rounded corners with quadratic Bézier curves
    d = `M${x1},${y1} 
         A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         Q${px2},${py2} ${x21},${y21} 
         L${x31},${y31}
         Q${px3},${py3} ${x3},${y3}
         A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         Q${px4},${py4} ${x41},${y41}
         L${x11},${y11}
         Q${px1},${py1} ${x1},${y1}Z`;

svgPath.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
```

(Those rounded corners are now tighter because I didn't get into your curves, but I assume you know which values to update to fix them.)

CodePen for you: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/VqeXxo

Comment: Yes I know which ones to update. Thank you so much for your help, @MSC!